# Find Duplicate Rows with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, find, duplicates

I need to identify duplicate rows in VBA (Note: a duplicate row implies equal values to the original row over all columns considered). I found a couple of programs to do this based on a certain column and I know duplicate rows can be found and deleted very quickly with `Range.RemoveDuplicates Method (Excel)` for whole rows, but that does not help me with the identification. Assume the following rows are given:

```
EE  10  12  13
jk  56  AA  00
BB  32  af  12
21  CC  CC  fg
as  DD  89  fg
AA  67  45  vb
fh  56  df  kl
cv  fh  CC  34
af  xv  DD  67
EE  10  12  13
```

In this example, the first and the last row are to be identified (either returned in a function or marked in some type of colour). Note that I do not want to delete them, but rather save them on a new sheet, but that is not the problem. The problem is just the identification.

With my real data I have about 30,000 rows, so performance is also quite important.

Comment: You want to identify duplicates from column A only or from every other column as well ?

Comment: Conditional formatting with formula  will be enough, Is there any specific reason to do it through VBA ?

Comment: No particular reason but I need to automize things. Excel does not get you very far in this regard :)

Comment: @Santosh duplicates are only duplicates over a full row, i. e. the same value in every single column. Edited in original thread.

Comment: One more thing why conditional formatting doesn't help: I have so many rows that it's very hard to scroll and look for some colour/formatting. I need the address in VBA, so I can manipulate it later on. Moreover I need to do this many times and not only once. More than one reason to rely on programming.

Comment: In that case you'll just have to write the code: (1) loop through the rows (2)  create an inner loop to compare the row to the remaining rows (3) compare using `if` statements. In order to keep the performance up you should probably do all of this in memory with an array and start with something like this: `aryAllRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheet").Range("A1:Z30000")` and then work with the array using `LBound` and `UBound`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub highlight()

    firstRow = 2
    lastrow = 30

    For j = firstRow To lastrow
        If Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 4)).Interior.Color = 255 Then
            'already highlighted, found to be duplicate.  Skip.
        For i = firstRow + 1 To lastrow
            If Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior.Color = 255 Then
                'already highlighted, found to be duplicate.  Skip.
            ElseIf Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 4) _
                = Cells(j, 1) & Cells(j, 2) & Cells(j, 3) & Cells(j, 4) Then
                'Dupe found, highlight as red
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior.Color = 255
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

You need a nested loop for this solution.  It's important to skip over items that are already found to be dupes, I use the highlighting for this.

Untested, but it should be close.

Comment: I just realized that this question was asked in 2013.  @tyop stop bringing up old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub szukanie()

    firstRow = 1
    lastrow = 13

    For j = firstRow To lastrow
        If Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 4)).Interior.Color = 255 Then
                For i = firstRow + 1 To lastrow
                    If Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior.Color = 255 Then
                        ElseIf Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 4) = Cells(j, 1) & Cells(j, 2) & Cells(j, 3) & Cells(j, 4) Then

                            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior.Color = 255

                    End If
                Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

**but u have to hilight a first row**